# Why Does Urysohn's lemma need the space to be Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

I've just finished a General Topology course. We used Dugundji's Topology book. There's one thing I don't understand regarding Urysohn's lemma: as stated in Dugundji's, it says: Let Y be a Hausdorff space. Then Y is normal if and only if  for every $A,B\subseteq Y$ closed and disjoint there's a continuous function $f:Y\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$, $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$.

My question is: Why do we ask for $Y$ to be Hausdorff beforehand? Do I need the Hausdorff property for the $\implies)$ part of the proof or for $\impliedby)$? I really can't see at what point I use it.

Just in case it helps (I'm at a loss and don't know if it will), the author already asks $Y$ to be Haussdorf when defining "normal" space.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the Urysohn lemma we do not need the extra separation axioms. This follows from studying the proof carefully, and is explicit in some topology texts (where a distinction is made between "normal" = separate disjoint closed sets by disjoint open sets and $T_4$  which is "normal plus $T_1$" (singletons are closed) which is the same as "normal plus Hausdorff" of course), where Urysohn's lemma is proved explicitly for "normal spaces". E.g. (if you read German) Boto von Querenburg, *Mengentheoretische Topologie*".

So Dugundji uses the word "normal" for what I called $T_4$ and so he has to assume Hausdorffness on $Y$ just to fulfill that extra separation axiom requirement. He probably knew full well that Hausdorffness was not needed for the proof, but wanted to exclude spaces like indiscrete spaces from the "nice class" of "normal" spaces. In practice, spaces we apply Urysohn's lemma in are indeed at least Hausdorff, and most topologists don't work in spaces which are not Hausdorff.

So TLDR; Urysohn's lemma and the closed-set-separation property are equivalent without Hausdorffness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to build a counterexample for the converse of Urysohn (if there's a urysohn function, then $Y$ is normal) by using topologies where $\{r\}$ is open, with no luck. I read your answer and think I got it, but just to make sure (I'm an undergraduate student, there's a ton of things I just don't grasp), I don't need Hausdorffness for the converse either? Are there normal-and-not-Hausdorff spaces that aren't trivial?

Comment: @Rasend If Urysohn holds, let $C$ and $D$ be disjoint closed and let $f$ be an Urysohn function. Then $U = f^{-1}[(-\infty, \frac12)]$ and $V = f^{-1}[(\frac12, +\infty)]$ are open in $X$ by continuity of $f$ and are disjoint and contain $C$ resp. $D$. So $X$ is normal.

Comment: @Rasend Any space that has the property that a closed set is also open (includes the trivial space, but also any sum space of trivial spaces) is normal, and the sum space example is another non-Hausdorff example when at least one of the summands has at least two points. Another way of seeing such spaces: they have a base that is a partition of $X$. The excluded point topology is another trivially normal space (there are no non-disjoint closed non-empty sets) that is not a trivial space.

Comment: @Rasend Berci's example is the sum of $[0,1]$ many copies of two point indiscrete spaces, or equivalently the partition topology generated by the partition $\{(x,0), (x,1)\}: x \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last paragraph, if $Y$ is normal, then it is also Hausdorff. So $\Rightarrow$ doesn't require this hypothesis.

On the other hand, there are non-Hausdorff spaces that satisfy the given property: for example take any normal space $Y$ and double its points: $X:=Y\times\{0,1\}$ with the topology inherited from $Y$ which glues $(y, 0)$ to $(y, 1)$, i.e. let $G\subseteq X$ be open iff $G=U\times\{0,1\} $ with $U$ open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The only thing I can think of is: Any indiscrete space is (trivially) Normal but not Hausdorff. So maybe the author asks for $Y$ to be Haussdorf so he eliminates that trivial case. But why? there's no need.

Comment: Yes, we can also take an indiscrete space: it trivially satisfies the condition, but it's not normal. To conclude $Y$ is normal, the Hausdorff hypothesis is necessary.